# Why the BorderType option is absent in OpenCV MedianBlur?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am working with OpenCV and I came to the question, why for example GaussianBlur have option for BorderType, but MedianBlur don't have?
I have researched about separable filters, maybe it's connected to that?
Because GaussianBlur is separable, but MedianBlur not.
And in the open source code of OpenCV is hard to understand why for example this two filters have that difference.

Comment: It seems that some smart guy decided that in the context of `medianBlur` using `borderType=BORDER_REPLICATE` will do for anybody. But when, e.g., trying to remove thin (grid) lines from an image, this border type will give unwanted results when the lines touch/cross the image border. My work around is to use `copyMakeBorder(..., top/bottom/left/right=ksize/2, borderType=BORDER_REFLECT_101)`. But since `medianBlur(...)` also adds a border, you have a little inefficiency here ...

Answer (score 0):

Probably because was decided that parameter is not needed in case of median filter. When algorithm calculates value for pixels close to the border of the image and neighborhood of that pixel outreach spatial image domain they just omit it in their implementation and calculating median from pixels placed on image only, but you could write implementation that instead of omitting that pixels consider them as 0 or 128 or 255 or some other value calculated from pixels near to them but that probably is not good approach.

For example if you have to calculate pixel value in the corner of image with median filter with mask size equals 3, when you calculate median from only four pixels placed on the image it's perfectly fine. You don't need all 9 pixels in the neighborhood. Adding some interpolated values could distort result.

Comment: But I have read the source code of MedianFilter, there is part of border. It uses cv::CopyMakeBorder , but just uses option BORDER_REPLICATE tag, but there are more than this one and can help in lot of situations.

Comment: And it's not done without padding, because it would be much slower than with padding.